# Nonmeasurable set with positive outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

It is well-known that any set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with positive outer measure contains a nonmeasurable subset $V$. I know that $0 < m^*(V) \le m^*(E)$. Nevertheless, my question is the following: given $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $r>0$, is there a nonmeasurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ whose outer measure is exactly $r$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a Vitali nonmeasurable subset of $[0,1]$, and scale it appropriately.

Comment: This is probably close enough to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/vitali-type-set-with-given-outer-measure to close as duplicate.  Note however that this problem is a bit easier, because given a nonmeasurable set $V$ with finite outer measure $s\gt 0$, the set $\frac{r}{s}V=\{\frac{r}{s}\cdot x:x\in V\}$ is a nonmeasurable set with outer measure $r$.

Comment: Thank you Arturo and Jonas. It was really simple.

Comment: I'll put my and Jonas's answer as a Community Wiki answer so you can mark it as "accepted" and the question can be marked as answered, in case it doesn't get the votes to be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can take a Vitali nonmeasurable subset of $[0,1]$, which has positive and finite outer measure, and just scale it appropriately.

As Jonas points out, this is closely related to [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/vitali-type-set-with-given-outer-measure), but much easier.