# What is the outer measure of Vitali set?

Tags: measure-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vitali-type set with given outer measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/vitali-type-set-with-given-outer-measure)

Given that the construction of [Vitali set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) is based on the axiom of choice. How can the outer measure of this set be calculated?

Comment: [It isn't determined](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/14591/) from the usual description alone.

Comment: @t.b. Many thanks, I guess this is a duplicate then. I will flag it.

Comment: No need to flag it. See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157532/, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/32214/

Comment: @t.b. If you post your comment as an answer with the references, I will accept it. This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate the coincidence between your name and the name of the set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Vital's request:

There isn't just one Vitali set: each choice of representatives of the equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$ given by $x \sim y$ if and only if $y - x \in \mathbb{Q}$ yields what one calls a Vitali set. You can arrange them to have any given positive outer measure you want.

There are many threads on this site where Vitali sets were discussed, among which:

- [Vitali-type set with given outer measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14591/)
- [Are Vitali sets dense in [0,1)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32214/)
- [Vitali set of outer-measure exactly $1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157532/)

You can find a few more by [Googling for `"Vitali set" site:math.stackexchange.com`](http://www.google.com/search?&q=%22Vitali+set%22+site:math.stackexchange.com)