# exterior measure and additivity

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently following Stein's book for Real Analysis.

It states as an observation with proof that if $E=E_1 \cup E_2,$ and $d(E_1,E_2)>0,$ then $m_*(E)=m_*(E_1) + m_*(E_2)$ where $m_*$ is the outer measure.

Am I right in saying that because $d(E_1,E_2)>0$ then the two sets are disjoint?

If so, the book then says that in general the above does not really hold for $E_1$ and $E_2$ disjoint.

I am a bit confused by this. What are some instances then for which the outer measure fails to be additive for disjoint sets?

Answer (score 1):

The notation $d(E_1,E_2)$ means $d(E_1,E_2)=inf\{d(x,y):x \in E_1, y \in E_2\}$. So if $d(E_1,E_2) > 0$, $d(x,y)>0$ for all $x \in E_1$, $y \in E_2$, and so $E_1$ and $E_2$ are disjoint. For an example of when outer measure is not additive for disjoint sets, you need to look at nonmeasurable sets. These can only be constructed with the axiom of choice. For an example, let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be two disjoint Vitali sets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set, [What is the outer measure of Vitali set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182870/what-is-the-outer-measure-of-vitali-set)). Two disjoint Vitali sets may be taken to have outer measure 1, but the union of two Vitali sets are still contained in [0,1].

Comment: i see. but why is it that the additivity was "proved" in Stein and later on mentioned that it is not necessarily true? In this case there must be something "wrong" with the "proof" then, no?