# Lebesgue Outer Measure: Vitali Set

Tags: measure-theory

What is the Lebesgue outer measure of a Vitali set and its complement over $\Omega=[0,1]$?

My first guess was zero and one but that was on my wrong idea that I can adjust the vitali set to lie within $[0,\varepsilon)$ changing it again and again... Also though its complement lies within $[\varepsilon,1]$ it is not guaranteed that there's a finer covering of it than that of $[\varepsilon,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is noted here:

[What is the outer measure of Vitali set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182870/what-is-the-outer-measure-of-vitali-set)

You may change the vitali set to have any possible Outer Measure if you construct it properly.

In general, it is not Lebesgue Measurable.

Comment: Ah so thats a duplicate - I'm sorry for that!

Comment: @Freeze_S No worries!