# Find the sup of a non-measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am currently studying E.Stein and R.Sharkarchi's Real Analysis. I have got a problem about the non-measurable set constructed in text named $N$.
I have proved that the outer measure of $[0, 1]-N$ is 1. And the outer measure of $N$ is dependent upon the choosing of element in each equivalence class, because you can choose one in each class to make the outer measure however small as you like.

### My question is : what is the supremum of the outer measure of $N$? Is it 1?

In case you need to revise the definition of $N$:
Construct an equivalence among all the real numbers in $[0,1]$, by:
If $a-b$ is rational, then a~b. Otherwise a and b are in different classes. Now we get a classification of real numbers between 0 and 1. Choose one element from each equivalent class, then these elements form a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$. Note it as $N$.

Comment: By "the supremum of the outer measure of $N$", are you taking the supremum over all $N$ that we can construct this way?

Comment: yeah, all the N. The difference just lies in how to choose element in each classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** The answer is that the supremum is $1$, but my proof for this fact was incorrect (so I am deleting it). Correct answers to the question are already available on this site, so I am linking to them instead.

- [What is the outer measure of Vitali set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182870/what-is-the-outer-measure-of-vitali-set)
- [Lebesgue Outer Measure: Vitali Set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916318/lebesgue-outer-measure-vitali-set)
- [Vitali set of outer-measure exactly $1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157532/vitali-set-of-outer-measure-exactly-1)

Comment: Sorry, could you explain why $(a, b) \subset E \cup X$?

Comment: I had missed this when writing the proof, but $[a, b]$ cannot be in $E \cup X$. However, the original question has already been answered on this site, so I am editing my answer to link there instead.