# does it exist a dense vitali set on [0 , 1]?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We know that a vitali set may not be dense on [0, 1] according to:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32218/1034911

now my question is that:

> does it exist a dense vitali set on [0 , 1]?

Comment: Yes, when you do not try to choose your representatives in a special manner, you will end up with a dense vitali set. However, to do this rigorously, you should do some things like take a countable basis of the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ and then choose one representative in each of these open sets or something.