# Some problems concerning regularity os measures.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a regular "outer" measure on $\mathbb{R}^N$ (for example, the Lebesgue outer measure). By regularity I mean that for all $A\subset \mathbb{R}^N$, there is $E$ measurable with $A\subset E$ and $\mu(A)=\mu(E)$.

I have two questions which are bothering me for a long time.

> 1 - Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^N$, $E$ measurable with $A\subset E$ and $\mu(A)=\mu(E)$. Let $Q$ be a cube. Is it true that $$\mu(A\cap Q)=\mu (E\cap Q)?$$
>
> 2- In the above conditions, is there any example for which $\mu(E\setminus A)\neq 0$?

Any idea or reference is appreciated.

Comment: That's a _very_ weak "regularity" condition. $\;$

Comment: Are you sure about your definitions? I only know regularity as follows: $\mu$ is regular if for each set $A$ there is a measurable set $E$ such that $\mu(A)=\mu(E)$ AND $A\subset E$.

Comment: You are right @sranthrop, let me fix it.

Comment: Does [Vitali set of outer-measure exactly 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157532/) answer part 2? For this subset of $E=[0,1]$, the outer measure is $1$. Yet, $\mu(E\setminus A)$ is positive, for else $A$ would be measurable.

Comment: This definitely answer question 2 @900sit-upsaday.

Comment: This question does not meet [your own question standard,](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16603/242) being a pure problem statement (PSQ), showing absolutely no work, no context, no knowledge-level, etc. Please improve the question. Please show some work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following additional conditions I give an answer to your question.

- For each set $A\subset\mathbb R^N$ there exists a measurable set $E$ such that $A\subset E$ and $\mu(A)=\mu(E)$.
- Q is measurable.

Since $A\subset E$ we clearly have $\mu(A\cap Q)\leq\mu(E\cap Q)$ and $\mu(A\backslash Q)\leq\mu(E\backslash Q)$. Since $Q$ and $E$ are measurable we have
$\mu(A\cap Q)=\mu(A)-\mu(A\backslash Q)=\mu(E)-\mu(A\backslash Q)\geq\mu(E)-\mu(E\backslash Q)=\mu(E\cap Q)$. Consequently, $\mu(A\cap Q)=\mu(E\cap Q)$.

Comment: If $Q$ is not measurable, do you think that equality may fail?

Comment: I think one could find a counterexample, but I am not sure.
Do you know anything else about your cube? Or about the measure? If $\mu$ were Borel regular for example, and if your cube were open/closed (=> Borel set), then you knew that it is automatically measurable.

Comment: In fact, in these particular cases you have solved the problem, I alread knew the solution (only for question 1), so I am more interested in the general case.