# Show that there exists $E\subset [0,1]$ such that $m^*(E)=m^*([0,1]\setminus E)=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that there exists $E\subset [0,1]$ such that
$$m^*(E)=m^*([0,1]\setminus E)=1$$

I have thought to use the Theorem: $A\subset R$ with the property that $A\cap B$ is unmeasurable for every Legesgue measurable set $B$ with $m(B)>0$

But I have trouble to considering why the outer measure of a vitali set can be any number.

Comment: You may benefit from the following along with the linked and related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157532/

Comment: @JonasMeyer   Thanks, but I don't understand why the outer measure of vitali set is an arbitrary number belongs to $[0,1]$

Comment: See the mathoverflow questions [Non Lebesgue measurable subsets with “large” outer measure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12935/non-lebesgue-measurable-subsets-with-large-outer-measure) AND [Is there a maximum to the amount of disjoint non-measurable subsets of the unit interval with full outer measure?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119646/is-there-a-maximum-to-the-amount-of-disjoint-non-measurable-subsets-of-the-unit).