# Defining a explicit and bijective function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ whose distribution of points in the graph of $f$ satisfy the motivation?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions, definition

This is connected to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709180/does-there-exist-an-explicit-and-bijective-function-that-satisfies-the-main-ques). The main difference is criteria 4.

**Main Question:**

Using the Lebesgue outer measure, does there exist an explicit and *bijective* function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ such that:

1. the function $f$ is measurable in the sense of Caratheodory
2. the graph of $f$ is dense in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$
3. the range of $f$ is $[0,1]$
4. for all real $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$, where $0\le x_1<x_2\le 1$ and $0\le y_1<y_2\le 1$, the Lebesgue measure of $f^{-1}([y_1,y_2])\cap[x_1,x_2]$ is $\ell$ where there exists an $z\in(0,1]$ *large enough* such that $(1-z)(y_2-y_1)(x_2-x_1)\le \ell \le (1+z)(y_2-y_1)(x_2-x_1)$ and all other criteria are satisfied
5. for every $\lambda\in(0,1]$, the graph of $f$ is as *non-uniform* as possible  in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$  i.e. (here is my attempt to rigorously define "non-uniformity")

> For $n,j\in\mathbb{N}$ (and $j<n$), suppose we partition set
> $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ into $n^2$ squares with length $n$, such that we combine these squares to form larger rectangles/squares with area $1/(j^2)$. Furthermore, we define $i,r,m,t\in\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{0\right\}$, where $y_{i+1}-y_i=1/n$ and $0\le i+r \le n-1$ such that the length of each of the rectangles/squares (parallel to the y-axis) is interval $[y_i,y_{i+r}]$ with length $1/(n+r)$. Also, suppose $x_{m+1}-x_m=1/n$, where $0\le m+t \le n-1$ and the side of each  rectangle/square (parallel to the x-axis) is interval $[x_m,x_{m+t}]$ with length $1/(n+t)$.
>
> If the Lebesgue measure on the sigma algebra of caratheodory-measurable sets is $\lambda$, then I would like to divide the Lebesgue measure of each $f^{-1}([y_{i},y_{i+r}])\cap[x_{m},x_{m+t}]$, if the area of $[y_i,y_{i+r}]\times[x_{m},x_{m+t}]$ is ${1}/{(j^2)}$, by the total area of all the "squares/rectangles with area $1/(j^2)$". This results in a discrete probability distribution $\mathbb{P}$:
>
> \begin{alignat}{3}
> & S(j,n)=\{&&(i,r,m,t): i,r,m,t\in\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{0\right\}, y_{i+1}-y_i=x_{m+1}-x_m=1/n, \\ & && \text{Area}([y_i,y_{i+r}]\times[x_{m},x_{m+t}])=1/j^2\}
> \end{alignat}
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(j,n)=\left\{\frac{\lambda(f^{-1}([y_{\text{i}},y_{\text{i}+\text{r}}])\cap[x_{\text{m}},x_{\text{m}+\text{t}}])}{1/(j^2)\cdot|S|}:\text{i},\text{r},\text{m},\text{t}\in S(j,n)\right\}$$
>
> We want to then take the [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) of the discrete distribution.
>
> $$\text{E}(\mathbb{P}(j,n))=\sum\limits_{x\in\mathbb{P}(j,n)}-x\log_{2}x$$
>
> Next, we wish to define the non-uniformity i.e. $\mathcal{U}(f,[0,1]\times[0,1])$ of a distribution using the limit in terms of $j$ and $n$ of the *relative similarity* of two distributions i.e., the subtraction of one and [the relative change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference) between $\text{E}(\mathbb{P}(j,n))$ and the entropy of a [discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) with cardinality $|S|$ i.e. $\log_{2}{|S|}$:
>
> $$\mathcal{U}(f,[0,1]\times[0,1])=1-\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log_{2}(|S|)-\text{E}(\mathbb{P}(j,n))}{\log_{2}(|S|)}\right)$$
>
> **Summary:** *For every $\lambda\in(0,1]$ (see criteria 4.), the value of $\mathcal{U}(f,[0,1]\times[0,1])$ should be as small as possible.*

6. using the Lebesgue measure, the expected value of $f$ is computable?

**Motivation:** I wanted to define an explicit and bijective function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ where the graph of $f$ is *somewhat* but not *too evenly* distributed (i.e. the measure on the graph of $f$ is the uniform probability measure on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$), such that using the [uniform probability measure](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2020/11/the_uniform_measure.html), we want a subset $X\subseteq[0,1]$, where (when function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is restricted to $f:X\to[0,1]$) the expected value of $f$ is undefined so we can *find an unique [extension of the expected value of $f$ which gives a finite value instead](https://www.overleaf.com/read/hcdxzgqsxmwd)*.

**Question on motivation:** If the function from the main question exists, does it satisfy the motivation?

**Attempt to Solve Both Questions:**

I can't prove an explicit example exists. For example, the [Conway base-13 function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) satisfies some criteria of the **main question** but is defined as $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, is [not computable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1156/1176963), and is surjective.

Furthermore, here is an attempt from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699235/does-the-following-non-measurable-function-exist), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699353/does-this-measurable-function-exist-and-satisfy-my-motivation), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4707128/does-this-explicit-and-bijective-measurable-function-exist-and-satisfy-my-motiva) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4710332/1176963) (*note in the links, neither of the main questions/answers satisfy the motivation*, e.g. in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4699323/1176963), the function wasn't very explicit; with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4706564/1176963), the function was *extremely* “non-uniform”; for the main question of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4707128/does-this-explicit-and-bijective-measurable-function-exist-and-satisfy-my-motiva), the answer may not satisfy the motivation; and for [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4710332/1176963), the function is also *extremely* "non-uniform"):

(I wish for a *simpler example*, since mine is too difficult to work with and I don't know what $z$ or $\mathcal{U}(f,[0,1]\times[0,1])$ should be using criterias 4. and 5. of the *main question*)

In case one wants to read here, here's the attempt:

> Suppose the base-$3$ expansion of real numbers, in interval
> $[0,1]$, have infinite decimals that approach $x\in[0,1]$ from the right
> side so when $0\le x_1,x_2\le 1$ (and $x_1=x_2$) we get $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.
>
> Furthermore, for $\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{0\right\}=\mathbb{N}_{0}$, if
> $r\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$ and $\text{digit}_{3}:\mathbb{R}\times
>  \mathbb{Z}\to\left\{0,1,2\right\}$ is a function where
> $\text{digit}_{3}(x,r)$ takes the digit in the $3^{r}$-th decimal fraction
> of the base-$3$ expansion of $x$ (e.g.
> $\text{digit}_{3}(1.789,2)=\text{digit}_{3}({1.210022{\cdot\cdot\cdot}}_{3},2)=1$), then $\left\{{g_r}^{\prime}\right\}_{r\in\mathbb{N}_{0}}$ is a
> sequence of functions (and $\left[\cdot\right]$ is the nearest integer
> function) such that ${g_r}^{\prime}:\mathbb{N}_0\to\mathbb{N}_0$ is
> defined to be:
>
> \begin{equation}
>   g_r^{\prime}(x)=\left[\frac{10}{3}\sin(rx)+\frac{10}{3}\right]
>  \end{equation}
>
> then for some function $k:\mathbb{N}_{0}\to\mathbb{N}_{0}$, where $k$ is strictly increasing and $k(0)$ is a positive
> number, we want the
> the intermediate function (before $f$) or $f_{1}:[0,1]\to[0,10]$
> to satisfy the **main question** (such that, in criteria 3. the range of $f_1$ is $[0,10]$).
>
> \begin{alignat}{2} & f_{1}(x)  =
>  &&\left|\left(\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty}
> g_{r+1}^{\prime}\!\left(\sum\limits_{p=r}^{r+k(r)}\text{digit}_{3}(x,p)\right)\!\!\bigg/3^{r}\right)-10\right|=
>  \label{eq:025} \\ & &&
> \left|\left(\left(\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{10}{3}\sin\left(\left(r+1\right)\left(\sum\limits_{p=r}^{r+k(r)}\text{digit}_{3}(x,p)\right)\right)+\frac{10}{3}\right]\right)\!\!\bigg
>  /3^{r}\right)-10\right| \nonumber \end{alignat}
>
> (One example of $k(r)$ that *may* satisfy main question, when with criteria 3. the range of $f_1$ is $[0,10]$ instead of $[0,1]$, is $k(r)=10r+20$)
>
> What we’re doing with $f_1$ is we are converting every digit of the base-$3$ expansion of $x$
> into a pseudo-random number that is non-equally likely to be an integer,
> including and in-between, $0$ and $20/3$. Furthermore, we attempt to
> make the function dense in $[0,1]\times[0,10]$ by adding the
> $3^{r}$-th decimal fraction with the next $3^k$-th decimal fractions; however, we also want to control the end-points of $[0,10]$, such that $f_1$
> is dense in $\left[0,1\right]\times\left[0,1\right]$ by manipulating $f_1$ to get:
>
> \begin{alignat}{2} & f(x)  = && 1-\frac{1}{10}f_1(x)\label{eq:109}\\
>  & && 
>  1-\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\left|\left(\left(\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{10}{3}\sin\left(\left(r+1\right)\left(\sum\limits_{p=r}^{r+k(r)}\text{digit}_{3}(x,p)\right)\right)+\frac{10}{3}\right]\right)\!\!\bigg/3^{r}\right)-10\right|
>  \nonumber \end{alignat}
>
> (e.g. where $k(r)=10r+20$). You can use programming to visualize $f$ though I
> don't know if you can graph the entire function. (The programming I
> used is mathematica.)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
k[r_] := k[r] = 
  20 (* You can adjust k[r]; however, mathematica is unable to graph \
f when k[r] is steepy increasing e.g. for this function, k[r] must be \
less than 25 for the code to show a graph. Instead, it should be k[r]=10r+20 *)

g1[xr_, r_] := 
 g1[xr, r] = 
  Round[(10/3) Sin[r xr] + (10/
      3)] (*Converts the (3^r)th decimal fraction,in the base 3 \
expansion of the x-values in[x1,x2] (defined as xr or x_r not x*r) \
into a psuedo-random number that's non-equally likely to spit a \
number between,and including, 0 and 20/3 *)

f[x_] := f[x] = 
  N[1 - ((1)/(10)) RealAbs[
      Sum[g1[Sum[
           RealDigits[x, 3, k[r], -r][[1]][[z]], {z, r + 1, k[r]}], 
          r + 1]/(3^r), {r, 0, 8}] - 
       10]] (*Defines function f,I assume the larger k[r]'s values, the more \
the function appears dense in [0,1]x[0,1]*)

p = .00005 (*Incremement between the x-values in the points of the \
graph below*)

ListPlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, p, 1, 
   p}]] (*Graphs countable points of the functions but is not a \
complete accurate graph. There are uncountably many points that need \
to be included.*)
```

[image: Image of Code]

Unfortunately, I only studied up to intro to advanced math. (Without a deep undestanding of mathematics I'm unable to prove if the function gives what I'm looking for.)

*Is there a simpler example?*

Comment: Made edits using this [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/13wswbo/does_this_function_exist/jmfm9tf/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=ioscss&utm_content=1&utm_term=1&context=3).

Comment: Made additional edits using this [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/13wswbo/comment/jmmdsv0/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: what does « the function  is measurable in the sense of Caratheodory » mean?

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Using the Lebesgue outer measure, the function $f$ every pre-image of the range of $f$ is in the sigma algebra of [caratheodory-measurable sets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion). (I don’t know if this is necessary; there may be other criteria that are not needed).

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan I meant the pre-image of every subset of the range of $f$....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that is it not possible.

Indeed, let $E = f^{-1}([0,1/2])$.

Condition 4 entails the existence of some constant $c>0$, such that for all  sub-interval $I$ of $[0,1]$, $c|I| \le |E \cap I| \le (1-c)|I|$. Since every open subset in $[0,1]$ is a countable union of disjoint interval, we get $c|O| \le |E \cap O| \le (1-c)|O|$ for every open subset $O$ in $[0,1]$.

By regularity of Lebesgue measure, for each $\varepsilon>0$, one can find open sets $O$ containing $E$ such that $|O| \le |E|+\varepsilon$, so $|E| \le (1-c)|O| \le (1-c)(|E|+\varepsilon)$. Letting $\varepsilon$ go to $0$ yields $|E| \le (1-c)|E|$, so $|E|=0$, which contradicts the inequality $c|I| \le |E \cap I|$ for all sub-interval $I$ of $[0,1]$.