# Creating a function that satisfies the following properties?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions, definition

Suppose using the lebesgue outer measure $\lambda^{*}$, we restrict $A$ to sets [measurable in the Caratheodory sense](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_criterion), defining the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$.

**Question:**

Does there exist an explicit and *bijective* $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, where:

1. The function $f$ is measurable
2. The graph of $f$, i.e. $\left\{(x,f(x)):x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$
3. The range of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$
4. For all real $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$, where $-\infty<x_1<x_2<\infty$ and $-\infty<y_1<y_2<\infty$:
   $$\lambda(\left([x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2]\right)\cap\left\{(x,f(x)):x\in\mathbb{R}\right\})>0$$

$\quad\quad\!$ and
$$\lambda(\left([x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2]\right)\cap\left\{(x,f(x)):x\in\mathbb{R}\right\})\neq(x_2-x_1)(y_2-y_1)$$

**Attempt:** I'm not sure how to answer this question but I heard of [Conway’s Base-13](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) function?

I have also asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4710339/1176963) with an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4714521/1176963) suggesting the function doesn’t exist.

Comment: I could find a function that satisfies the first three conditions, but point 4 seems especially tough to me. Would you happen to know if those two inequalities are even possible if we replaced the graph of $f$ by a general subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @WillowWisp Actually, according to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/451445/504799) such a function is impossible to find.