# Example of disjoint union of sets which does not have additive measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I had a question about the additivity property of the outer measure.

Can someone provide an example of a disjoint union of sets which doesn't have an outer measure equal to the sum of the outer measure of each set (in $\mathbb{R}^n$)? That is:

$m_*(E_1\bigcup E_2)\neq m_*(E_1) + m_*(E_2)$, where $E_1\bigcap E_2=\emptyset$ and $d(E_1,E_2)$ possibly equal to zero.

The theorem states this holds in general if $d(E_1,E_2)> 0$, but I can't find a counterexample where it doesn't if $d(E_1,E_2)=0$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, a clarification on terminology. The property that you are mentioning is what makes an outer measure a [metric outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_outer_measure). Lebesgue measure is a metric outer measure, so we know that $m_*(E_1\bigcup E_2)= m_*(E_1) + m_*(E_2)$, where $E_1\bigcap E_2=\emptyset$ must be true if $d(E_1,E_2)>0$.

---

Now, to your question. An outer measure is additive on the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets $\mathcal{M}$. In fact, if $E_1, E_2 \in \mathcal{M}$, we have
$$
m_*(E_1\cup E_2)=m_*((E_1\cup E_2)\cap E_1)+m_*((E_1\cup E_2)\cap E_1^c)= m_*(E_1) + m_*(E_2),
$$
using the definition of measurable set.
So we need to look for a counterexample among non-measurable sets. Note that [Solovay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_M._Solovay) proved in 1970 that the existence of a non-measurable set is possible only if we assume the Axiom of Choice, so there won't be a trivial answer to your question.

---

The most famous construction of a non-measurable set is the [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).
As in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/vitali-type-set-with-given-outer-measure) by JDH, we can construct a Vitali set $V$ in such a way that is contained in $[0,a]$, for any $a \in (0,1)$. Also, since the [inner measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_measure) of $V$ is zero, we have that $m_*([0,a]\setminus V)=a$ and then $[0,a]\setminus V$ is a non-measurable set of measure $a$. 
Note that we must have $m_*(V)>0$, because a set is measurable if and only if its outer and inner measures coincide, and we know the latter to be zero.
Then we have, by setting $E_1=V$ and $E_2= [0,a]\setminus V$,
$$
a=m_*([0,a])=m_*(E_1 \cup E_2) < m_*(E_1)+m_*(E_2)=a + m_*(V).
$$

Comment: It is a wonderful construction! I'd have a question... Why are we requiring $a \in (0,1)$ and not just $a \in \mathbb{R}$? Is it necessary somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Let $B$ be a [Bernstein set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set) in $\mathbb R$.  Then both
$$
E_1 = [0,1] \cap B \qquad \text{and}\qquad E_2 = [0,1]\setminus B
$$
have inner measure zero and outer measure one.  But they are disjoint with union $[0,1]$.  Now $0 + 0 \ne 1$ so inner measure is not additive, and $1+1 \ne 1$ so outer measure is not additive.

Answer (score 1):

Let Continuum Hypothesis $2^{\omega}=\omega_1$  is valid. Then we have the following representation $[0,1]=(x_{\xi})_{\xi<\omega_1}$. We put $A=\{ (x_{\eta}, x_{\xi}): \eta <\xi <\omega_1\}$ and 
$B=\{ (x_{\eta}, x_{\xi}):\omega_1> \eta \ge \xi\}$. It is obvious that $A\cup B=[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Then we get $1=m^*(A \cup B)\neq m^*(A)+m^*(B)=1+1=2$, where $m^*$ denotes an outher measure  produced by Lebesgue measure $m$ in $R^2$. If we denote by $m_*$ an inner measure produced by $m$, then we get $1=m_*(A\cup B)\neq m_*(A)+m_*(B)=0+0=0$.

Comment: Hint: For proof use Fubini theorem.