# Is it possible to construct a Vitali set $H$ so that the outer measure $\lambda^*(H)<\epsilon$?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

A Vitali set is a subset $V$ of $[0,1]$ such that for every $r\in \mathbb R$ there exists one and only one $v\in V$ for which $v-r \in \mathbb Q$. Equivalently, $V$ contains a single representative of every element of $\mathbb R / \mathbb Q$.

For any $\epsilon>0$, is it possible to construct a Vitali set $H$ so that the outer measure $\lambda^*(H)<\epsilon$?

Comment: Yes; you can generalize the construction to a small interval and outer measure still respects monotonicity.

Comment: @kodiak Can you please say more details about this construction?

Comment: The idea is that nothing goes wrong if you change $[0, 1]$ to $[0, \epsilon]$ in the usual construction of a Vitali set. When you do that, you get a set with outer measure at most $\epsilon$ by monotonicity. Discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14623/473276) as well.